# How to obtain an Executor?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, parallel-processing, google-mlkit

Reading [this guide](https://developer.android.com/media/camera/camerax/analyze#kotlin) on how to analyze images fed directly from the camera; in the code example on the bottom of the page there suddenly pops up a new variable `executor`:

```
imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, ImageAnalysis.Analyzer { imageProxy ->
```

Looked it up, an [Executor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor) is just another parallelization abstraction. Now, how do I get one? Is there something like this?

```
androidThreadPool.getExecutor()
```

Actually, I found one:

```
Context.getMainExecutor()
```

If I understand this correctly, this would execute the Runnable on the main thread. However, I assume the point of providing an Executor to the ImageAnalyzer is to *not* run it on the main thread.

Or do I have to create my own Executor? Is this common practice to do so?

Comment: I don't program Android (although I'm learning) but this appears to work the same way as regular Java.  If you read that link on Executors, you'll see that Executor is an interface, and further down in the documentation that the class ExecutorService is provided as an implementation.  The class `Executors` has factory methods for you to use.  For example: `pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);`

Comment: `this would execute the Runnable on the main thread.` Runnable is a fairly old interface, in new code I'd at least consider using `Callable<T>` instead.

Comment: EZ link to ExecutorSevice: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService  There's also a `ForkJoin` pool that can provide its own executors if fork-join happens to fit your use case.

Comment: Please do not tag both `java` and `kotlin`.

Comment: Firm disagree on tagging both Java and Kotlin; answers usually overlap and certainly would for a question like this.

Comment: for Java I would check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) of `Executor`: "... The [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class provides convenient factory methods for these Executors. ..."

Comment: I waited on this but gotta agree with Louis @MarcinOrlowski Java and Kotlin are different enough that tagging both is appropriate.  I answered based on Java knowledge but I would have never seen this question if it was only tagged Kotlin.

Comment: @markspace Runnable is a perfectly fine interface to use. The difference between Runnable and Callable is whether you need to get a value back. You should prefer the one that does what you need, not just one that is *newer*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> an Executor is just another parallelization abstraction

No, not “just another”. The Executors framework was a major milestone in the evolution of Java. This framework relieved the burden of managing threads from the shoulders of Java programmers, making concurrency work much simpler.

#### `ExecutorService`, not `Executor`

The `Executor` interface is *not* the most commonly used part. That interface defines the [`execute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)) method which *may* run your task on a background thread or may just as well run the task on the current thread.

If you know you want a background thread, use an implementation of the `ExecutorService` sub-interface with its methods like `submit`.

> how do I get one

Usually, we obtain an unspecified implementation of [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) by calling a convenient factory method on the `Executors` class.

You may want an executor service backed by a pool of any number of threads. Use this only when you know you a limited number of simultaneous tasks, so as to not overburden your machine.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool() ;
```

You may want an executor service backed by a pool of a certain number threads.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( maxThreadsCount ) ;
```

In modern Java, versions 21+, we use [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) for most purposes. I assume Android does not offer virtual threads, and won’t any time soon.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() ;
```

Any of these executor services can run your tasks you define as either a `Runnable` or a `Callable`.

> Or do I have to create my own Executor?

No, that would be a very rare situation where you would need a custom executor service.

> Is [creating my own executor] common practice to do so?

No.

The purpose of the Executors framework is to *avoid* dealing with the low-level details of juggling threads and tasks. Several good implementations of `ExecutorService` are bundled with Java, made available to you via `Executors` class.

---

Caveat: I don’t know Android. My comments here apply to the Java platform. My comments may also apply to Android; I just don’t know.

Comment: One thing I didn't immediately notice was that `ExecutorService` actually implements the `Executor` interface. With that, it is indeed straight forward to get an `Executor` from `Executors`.

Comment: @user1785730 Yes, every `ExecutorService` object is also an `Executor` object. But if you treat it as an `Executor`, you will have access only to the `execute` method which may or **may not** run on a background thread. As an `Executor`, you would *not* have access to the `submit` and `invoke…` methods that are guaranteed to run on background threads.